# Finding intersection of the lines in the image without using Hough lines transform or OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I wish to find the intersection of the lines in the following image without using OpenCV or Hough Line Transform (since it is computationally costly for my requirement).

I have tried creating a sliding window protocol and assigning weights based on symmetricity within the window, it takes a longer time as well.

I am looking for some innovative or even out of the box idea to approach this problem. Would love to brainstorm your ideas.

**Common features in the image:**
The images I am working on will more or less look the same. It is always a binary image and it is possible to know the number of intersections (in rows and columns) beforehand.

[image: Output from Adaptive threshold]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

By binarizing and getting contours, then selecting on area, you can obtain a number of isolated grid cells. You can use the centers to reconstruct the grid and predict the grid lines.

Then you can refine these lines by local edge detection near the predicted locations.

[image]